# Quadratic Weighted Kappa metric in H2O package for model performance

Tags: r, multi-class, h2o

I am running a multiclassification problem and before I make a function by myself I was wondering if anyone knows of a pre built quadratic weighted kappa function in the h2o library.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like H2O-3 has a function available to get the quadratic weighted kappa (though you can always create a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and request it as a feature). If your dataset isn't too big, you could run a model in H2O-3, get the predictions, convert those predictions to an R Dataframe and then use one of the R packages, like caret, that supports this metric to get it.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing - using another library. Thanks for the response though

Comment: I'm likely doing that myself.  'caret::confusionMatrix'